# Chrome App making page unresponsive

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, vaadin, google-chrome-app

We have Vaadin 6 application in which we have implemented Google/Facebook oauth2 for login, which is working perfectly in production (https://apps.thecloudstream.com). We have google market place app and chrome store app both pointing to our special url ((http://apps.thecloudstream.com/marketpace/google) which we have handled through a URI handler.

A strange issue I am stuck in for last two days is that when we add Chrome store app our page becomes unresponsive while after removing extension every thing becomes fine. Looking more deeply we are attaching `HttpServletRequestListener` when any of the button is pressed (google/facebook) for oauth2 login.

The login process also goes fine and we are able to fetch user info but when this info is returned from google/facebook servers, our `onRequestStart()` is hit and then we perform the rest but in this particular case this method is not hit and page becomes unresponsive.If we hit from another tab then our code goes into `onRequestStart()` and then flow becomes fine.

Can any one point me what I am doing wrong. I was trying to debug using GWT plugin but it is not working as google closing it.

**UPDATE**: after more digging into the code I found the following call is causing page unresponsive

```
 writeAjaxPage(request, response, window, application);
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try [timeline profiling](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to understand what is exactly the cause, but some hints I got, not sure about them but experts can confirm, that chrome apps run in a separate container and cannot handle redirects and there is a library for oauth using chrome apps, but in my case I'm not using that so I found a workaround i.e.

I created an html page on a separate domain that is simply redirecting to my actual url  and put it in the chrome app which solves the issue.